# Uniform convergence and differentiation intervals

Tags: real-analysis

I have learned:
If a sequence of differentiable functions converges pointwise on an interval $[a,b]$ and their derivatives converge uniformly on $[a,b]$ then we can differentiate term by term.

Is it true that we can replace $[a,b]$ with $[a, \infty)$ or perhaps an open interval?? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you speaking of the functions Taylor expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly for $x\in [a,\infty)$ then in particular, it converges uniformly on each compact interval $[a,b] \subset [a,\infty)$, so we can differentiate term by term in $[a,b]$. Since every point $x\in [a,\infty)$ can be fit into such an interval $[a,b]$, the term-by-term derivative applies everywhere on $[a,\infty)$.

If $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $(a,b)$, and it converges pointwise at $a$ and at $b$, then it converges uniformly on $[a,b]$.

We can get one bonus from $f_n(x)$ converging uniformly on $[c,\infty)$. If $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left ( \lim_{x\to\infty} f_n(x) \right )$ exists, then $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left ( \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) \right )$ exists and is equal to the former.